# java LDAP authentication works, C Sharp does not, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, ldap

I have the following Java program that works, with the real IP address, username, and password filled in for the fake values below:

```
package com.mycom;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String ... args)
  {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.go();
  }

  public void go()
  {
    Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<>();

    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "LDAPS://1.2.3.4:636/o=Some%20University"); // obviously I use a real IP address
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=jblow, ou=People, o=Some University");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "BigTeamFanPassword");

    try
    {
      Context context = new InitialContext(env);
      System.out.println("no exceptions...");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }


  }
}
```

If jblow's password is correct, this succeeds, otherwise an exception is thrown.

I'm now trying to do the same thing with the same server in C Sharp:

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols;

using System.Net;

namespace LdapTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string host = "LDAPS://1.2.3.4:636"; 
            using (LdapConnection con = new LdapConnection(host))
            {
                con.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
                con.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
                con.Credential = new NetworkCredential("uid=jblow", "BigTeamFanPassword", "ou=People, o=Some University");
                con.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
                try
                {
                    con.Bind();
                    Console.WriteLine("No exception");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("exception, " + e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried various things, like putting the organization with "/o=org" after the port number in the host string, etc., and I'm tired of trial and error.  Can someone tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: oh, sorry -- "The LDAP server is unavailable"

Comment: Is the LDAP server certificate trusted by your machine? What TLS versions does the LDAP server accept, and have you tried viewing the output in Wireshark?

Comment: It's good to check the date on posts, especially ones you're answering. This one is 7 years old. I am no longer working on this problem.